# Matplotlib bug in histogram - all stacked in one bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

When I run :

```
plt.hist('%s/draws.csv' % CONFIG['build']['draw_data'])
```

I get this weird histogram, [image]
all my data is put under the same frequency bar, and I cannot get rid of the file path below, neither show x.ticks.
Its weird because, my data is simply a csv file exported from `np.random.normal(size=100000)`.

When I run directly the code :

```
data = np.random.normal(size=10000)
plt.hist(data)
```

I get a normal histogram :
[image]

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Probably you read the file in as text without converting to numbers.

Comment: @JohanC, what do you mean exactly ? im very new

Comment: Usually with pandas, you'd read your csv as `df = pd.read_csv('%s/draws.csv' % CONFIG['build']['draw_data'])` which normally takes care of properly converting strings to numbers. And then you'd call `df.hist(column='your_column_name')` or maybe `plt.hist(df['your_column_name'])``.  In your code, you don't seem to read in the file, you just use the filename as a string. Matplotlib doesn't know that you'd want to use that name to read in a file, nor which format that file has.